# invalid mount path: '[' mount path must be absolute

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have Dockerfile that looks like this

```
FROM clkao/postgres-plv8:12-2
VOLUME [ "/cfg" ]
ADD wait-for-env.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT [ "wait-for-env.sh", "/cfg/commondb.env", "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

In my `docker-compose` file I have the definition for the app

```
commondb:
restart: "no"
container_name: commondb
build: 
  context: ./postgres
  args: 
    - build_version
    - build_type
image: commonpostgres:$build_version
ports:
  - "5532:5432"
volumes: 
  - /Users/Projects/work/app/cfg:/cfg
networks:
  - common_network
```

The project layout looks like this

```
app/
    /cfg
    /postgres
        Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
```

When I try to run the command

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build commondb
```

I get this error

```
invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '[' mount path must be absolute
```

What is the problem?

Docker inspect for the image that includes VOLUME

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:75305aec38e534124a4463fd7d9b1db2729c9ab6f7a577bae03ba2bf1d3f60b4",
        "RepoTags": [
            "commonpostgres:3.5.0.0"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:0d6739604f9c967bc553d9ef86fab26bf04148ec808d017544a64ea11a4afce0",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2021-04-28T21:31:59.495950295Z",
        "Container": "4b4a9fa0b7b568fab8cc8c08b4d1d808cf239bebdb4f7b4e99468807c7e5ee1b",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "4b4a9fa0b7b5",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.11",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=12",
                "PG_VERSION=12.0-2.pgdg100+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "PLV8_VERSION=2.3.13",
                "PLV8_SHASUM=1a96c559d98ad757e7494bf7301f0e6b0dd2eec6066ad76ed36cc13fec4f2390"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"postgres\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:0d6739604f9c967bc553d9ef86fab26bf04148ec808d017544a64ea11a4afce0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/cfg": {},
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "wait-for-env.sh",
                "/cfg/commondb.env",
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.0",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.11",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=12",
                "PG_VERSION=12.0-2.pgdg100+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "PLV8_VERSION=2.3.13",
                "PLV8_SHASUM=1a96c559d98ad757e7494bf7301f0e6b0dd2eec6066ad76ed36cc13fec4f2390"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:0d6739604f9c967bc553d9ef86fab26bf04148ec808d017544a64ea11a4afce0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/cfg": {},
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "wait-for-env.sh",
                "/cfg/commondb.env",
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 454477235,
        "VirtualSize": 454477235,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c43f2711d56d01bf0fefefb817fb57b90b71dcc66a8caf14e5be023a3937412b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/30849bcdc6fa46adc8143fb024581eeba3f4782e934efa1699e286a08598eb36/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8bf9f40aff831f3fdafe0e1fb927cc48217b196dcea61cddb9333fc2aa9e2158/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5394092f6731a527286ebbcb937ebf4205f3a8d47e85858c666cb668b268ed2e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5b97a6dcb82b989d7bc148c3562deafc5a1fcc54f6914dba2c3d015d9bfb673/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b8b9c7d1df726a42880c7c3d79906ba99d05b5cc2c529fe8c926cd3a1c6de43f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9ce8b97437eb97ca8496407dabd1e42f0e29777770341c6656f3f41967b03064/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0986240c02d95212640a3548ec0c779dd8848ebfcbb5fe6d76ee1ee21bf8b7bc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b0401675a6ea74611dcaadd21277d0c345040cf90e4a602441693f5978a74af7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f7dc7b63d69e0f980d667d77235b8ae4d4480970b66adf1022d7d0b4c28e301/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/40062a1fff7fe08f66a701c7f9e74bb6176b6ffba64c200bbd34161200be7805/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f3c26a8b6785a27acfff5d864b230b412f5f21fc0b97c9f6eb33721a7d20e289/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6281953415b6ca1ceb9f45d081e894ef80b305e1886e5dcd2f65456ec76f8b0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/20d6863a2e45a495c87219c484e646d35be097a61e245b03f69254251b0c0eba/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2f5affd0345af000c105d98bc09292c072d70112943b2fe39d018007a12ce24/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8fc58d4a6afb173f6bcc9817244884631e51be84b2ef877597de774f8c7cb2cb/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8fc58d4a6afb173f6bcc9817244884631e51be84b2ef877597de774f8c7cb2cb/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8fc58d4a6afb173f6bcc9817244884631e51be84b2ef877597de774f8c7cb2cb/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:b67d19e65ef653823ed62a5835399c610a40e8205c16f839c5cc567954fcf594",
                "sha256:3ba344018aaff62dd13803a69103c3d558772f57d473f0017fe71fc642c197ac",
                "sha256:809946863d5edc06613a9ca26ef18fa8ba643455414791fc3ce1dde763abcf6d",
                "sha256:ddb50a567803b21f5e965a754a7ac6044d168a4c69adef21fb798203357d776b",
                "sha256:64f23a63821fa976eeafdcdaefe6a134c3a30a2929f25faea3fce7d967c96f20",
                "sha256:22f5303efdd797b083171067b63dfb55016f9ebb382ea754c8f8b12de57a0e07",
                "sha256:9cf9bdafe72ee52884b1924b9a3d52efab48ea16a3ccebeabf4c842721084358",
                "sha256:662023ffbbc50f4d9d9944649d7c7a7a1cd144a0340a1811939f0aabbdb06650",
                "sha256:a6a5c9284280aa35ea39c4cd2e5034d8e90f68607bad3825ab7762fcd9e10c5f",
                "sha256:8f168552100645641000e1da3c19651f1de531160171280c3df5a3c9d36c5dd0",
                "sha256:038d255941805552d62e75ba9ee0bfadb6cfd9ba6382736c974de17960b82a44",
                "sha256:9b3cf71cdd1a0cf3a34a043cc57adc92e38b233ae2782426c3c17ebe773b9c90",
                "sha256:db69dddb79103c20dc4f1b603f9413411dc0ba8ead21abcc4a3d2ea2707a2692",
                "sha256:eb866fc784eaeac79c170d29d28986cced57b1b19d7601885eaf32b46cfbe860",
                "sha256:93c4e7a68f1d76d09e39d2cbd8e9ba566c5479175699a87d4cd85b813468f464",
                "sha256:7476cca7ed2915679c64704742543509b3650b0409ead1b2cf143c223d0936e9"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2021-04-28T22:11:51.141550664Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: At a guess, this is related to the `VOLUME` statement in your Dockerfile (though it does look syntactically valid).  It's not necessary and mostly only has confusing side effects; does deleting it help?

Comment: No, still the same issue

Comment: Please include the output of `docker inspect` on your commonpostgres image.

Comment: @BMitch attached the inspect output

Comment: @BMitch I updated inspect to use image that contains VOLUME

Comment: Doesn't look like the `[` came from the image build, so I'd look to the compose file. The file is white space and version specific, and there can be multiple volume seconds (per service and top level). The current compose file has formatting issues in the question, so I'd double check that and update it.

Comment: Could you try to change your Dockerfile from VOLUME [ "/cfg" ] to VOLUME "/cfg"? That's basically the only part where you specify a "[" and the docker documentation does not seem to be very clear on that point.